# getting external storage data through CursorAdapter not instantly updateing on screen i build for

Tags: android, listview, android-cursoradapter, android-external-storage

I am grabbing audio data from a specific folder "voices" in a file manager and applying CursorAdapter on it, maight it's work properly but while i add new voice record to the "voices" it's not instantly appear to the screen its need much time and many stop application here is the code i did at RecordList activity and CursorAdapter, I want it to appear immediatly as voice added to "voices". I would be very glad if some one resolve that issue.

**RecordList Activity where voices displayed**

```
 mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    mMusicList=new ArrayList<>();
    mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.recording_list);


    recordsCursorAdapter=new RecordsCursorAdapter(this,null);
    mListView.setAdapter(recordsCursorAdapter);

   /* mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                                long arg3) {
            try {
                playSong(mMusicList.get(arg2).getAudioName());
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });*/
    getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(AUDIO_LOADER,null,this);
}


private void playSong(String path) throws IllegalArgumentException,
        IllegalStateException, IOException {
    String extStorageDirectory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
            .toString();
    path = extStorageDirectory + File.separator + path;

    mMediaPlayer.reset();
    mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(path);
    mMediaPlayer.prepare();
    mMediaPlayer.start();
}

@Override
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {

    String selection = MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA +" LIKE '%/voices/%'";
    return new CursorLoader(this,
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
            null,
            selection,
            null,
            null);
}

@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor mCursor) {
recordsCursorAdapter.swapCursor(mCursor);
}

@Override
public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {
recordsCursorAdapter.swapCursor(null);
}
```

**RecordCursorAdapter (CursorAapter)**

```
public class RecordsCursorAdapter extends CursorAdapter{


public RecordsCursorAdapter(Context context,Cursor c){
    super(context,c,0);
}

@Override
public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
    return LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.single_list_item,parent,false);
}

@Override
public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor mCursor) {
    TextView name= (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.audio_name);
    TextView details= (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.audio_details);

    String displayName = mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME));
    Log.e("name:",displayName);
    long durationMs=mCursor.getLong(mCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DURATION));
    Date date = new Date(durationMs);
    DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
    String dateFormatted = formatter.format(date);
    String dateTime=mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATE_ADDED));
    long size=mCursor.getLong(mCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.SIZE));
    String sizeKb=String.valueOf(size/1024);


    name.setText(displayName);
    details.setText(dateFormatted+" on "+dateTime+" "+sizeKb+"kb");
}
```

Comment: why too big images

Comment: i removed the images can you please provide the solution.

Comment: @pskink i tried but failed. i need some more details about it.